# original document about the patent US532942 (Charles Bivort et Jean Nadler)

Tags: documents

for an exhibition in Luxembourg, I am searching for an original document about the patent US532942 (Charles Bivort et Jean Nadler). How and where can I find this document?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP and enter the patent number in the Smart Search tab.It will retrive you the result (there is no title dispayed, probably because this is an old patent). Click on the result and then you can retrieve the pdf as the "original document".

Espacenet has a large collections of patent documents, from europe (EP and national pantens), USA, Korea, Japan, China, Australia, Canada and many more.